# Adding a template parameter to API struct and maintaining backwards compatibility with partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, backwards-compatibility

I have a software component with an API I maintain with clients.
Below is a simplification of my problem.

This is part of the interface:

```
typedef unsigned int CustomerId;
template <typename DataType>
struct CommandResult
{
    std::map<CustomerId, DataType> data;
};
```

And in the API there's a long list of API methods such as this:

```
APIResult APIMethod(input_parameters, CommandResult<SomeType>& output);
```

Now I'm adding a few new API methods, which require a slightly different CommandResult. So we'll call it GeneralCaseCommandResult:

```
template <typename ID, typename DataType>
class GeneralCaseCommandResult 
{
    std::map<ID, DataType> data;
};
```

It's very useful to me to keep both CommandResult types in the same struct because I reuse a lot of code internally by using templates.

However, I don't want to force my clients to change a lot of code just to replace CommandResult, so I did this:

```
template <typename DataType>
class CommandResult : public GeneralCaseCommandResult<CustomerId, DataType> {};
```

and everything's peachy.

Now I want to call my API methods from within some of my templated functions, like this:

```
template <typename ID, typename DataType>
void MyInternalFunc()
{
    GeneralCaseCommandResult<ID, DataType> output;

    // Will not compile
    APIResult res = APIMethod(params, output);

    ...
}
```

This of course will not work since the existing API methods receive CommandResult, and not its base class.

I tried creating a traits class per ID/DataType to hold the CommandResult type, and specialize it on CustomerId to support CommandResult. However it doesn't work since **the other ID's are also typedefs of unsigned int** (I use them to maintain order and readability in my code and API).

I also found Q&A here that I can't specialize on two typedefs which are actually the same type, and since these are just numeric ID's I don't want to use structs instead of int.

Any ideas how I can call my APIMethod from within the templated function while keeping all the above requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution might be default template parameters, if that works for you:

```
typedef unsigned int CustomerId;
template <typename DataType, typename ID = CustomerId>
struct CommandResult
{
    std::map<ID, DataType> data;
};
```

If that doesn't do the trick my next suggestion would be to use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` to create all the id types that aren't CustomerId, causing each one to be a distinct type you can create traits for.

Comment: It seems so obvious when I re-read the title to my question... Works like a charm. Thanks.